# INSERT OR REPLACE failed to add value of primary key in FLASH BUILDER 4.6

Tags: sqlite, apache-flex, replace, insert, insert-update

I am working with flash builder to handle some data updates in SQLite database.

I created two identical table with different names: T1 and T2.

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(
  id int NOT NULL,
  theData text,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE T2
(
  id int NOT NULL,
  theData text,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

I also put some test data into T2.

```
INSERT INTO T2 (id,theData) VALUES (1,'THEDATA-AA');
INSERT INTO T2 (id,theData) VALUES (2,'THEDATA-BB');
INSERT INTO T2 (id,theData) VALUES (3,'THEDATA-CC');
INSERT INTO T2 (id,theData) VALUES (4,'THEDATA-DD');
```

"SELECT * FROM T2" in sqlite command line to confirm the insert.

```
1|THEDATA-AA
2|THEDATA-BB
3|THEDATA-CC
4|THEDATA-DD
```

Then, execute the sql statement as below in my flex desktop project:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO T1 SELECT * FROM T2;
```

Then I tried to check the data in sqlite command line environment:

```
sqlite> select * from t1;
|THEDATA-AA
|THEDATA-BB
|THEDATA-CC
|THEDATA-DD
```

Where is the data of first column(id)? NOTE: the id is set to not only PK but NOT NULL as well.

```
sqlite> select id from t1;
sqlite>
```

NO RECORD?!

```
sqlite> select thedata from t1;
THEDATA-AA
THEDATA-BB
THEDATA-CC
THEDATA-DD
sqlite>
```

Data displayed when select "theData" column.

Then I performed several test only to find out that:

1. "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO T1 SELECT * FROM T2;" works FINE when executed in SQLITE command line.
2. Only happens when target table has ONE primary key. That is, a table with two or more primary key worked fine.
3. "INSERT OR IGNORE " also failed to insert the primary key value.
4. Change the sequence of columns did NOT help.
5. Add column name did NOT help: "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO T1 (id,theData) SELECT id,theData FROM T2" results the same.

I tried to find answers over internet but failed. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to `DROP TABLE t1;` and them rebuild your example? You may have a table `t1` with different schema and data and not checking for SQL errors...

Comment: Are you trying to write Flex code?  Or are you using an Eclipse Plugin for SQLLite?

Comment: >>Did you try to DROP TABLE t1?    >> YES. I tested it several times creating new database.

Comment: >>Are you trying to write Flex code? >>I am using Adobe Flash Builder 4.6. I created Flex Project on both Desktop (windows 7) and Mobile(iPhone emulator) to perform a test. Both failed.